# Users redirected to old site

Tags: login

If I login as admin, all is fine. However if I log in as a user, then it redirects to the old test site (development server used to get the site running).
I have checked siteurl and home values are correct in the database.
I am also using paid membership pro plugin.
I searched the database and found 740 entries of the old URL :(

Can anyone advise as to the best way forward without breaking the live site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For any change (especially when it comes to database), you will need to backup first. But for changing old links from WordPress admin area, I frequently use [Search and Replace plugin.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/)

You could try changing the links using this plugin, but make sure you have a full backup of both database and files before making any changes. Let us know if that resolves your issue.